# CDF of an Autoregressive Distribution

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Say I have an AR(1) process
$$x_{i+1} = \theta_1 + \theta_2 x_i + \epsilon , \quad \epsilon \sim N(0, 1),$$
with joint PDF
$$p(x_{0:1}) = p(x_0)p(x_{1}|x_0), \quad x_0 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2).$$

I am interested in calculating the CDF as the product of the conditional CDFs. The CDF of $p(x_0)$ is trivially
$$\phi\bigg(\frac{(x_0 - mu)}{\sigma}\bigg),$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of the unit normal. However, can I treat $p(x_{1}|x_0)$ in the same way. That is, is the CDF of $p(x_{1}|x_0)$ given by
$$\phi\bigg(\frac{(x_0 - \mu_1)}{\sigma_1}\bigg),$$
where $p(x_{1}|x_0) \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$, or do I need to intergrate out over $x_0$, such that the CDF is actually
$$\int \phi\bigg(\frac{(x_0 - \mu_1)}{\sigma_1}\bigg) p(x_0) dx_0.$$